# Smarty Combine internal get variable with another value

Tags: smarty

I'm trying to build a foreach loop in smarty where i have to access specific get vars like "user_1", "user_2" etc to mark checkboxes as checked. So what i need is smth like

```
{if $smarty.get.user_{$foreach_current_user_id} == "on"}checked{/if}
```

but this doesn't work. 
Is there a way to pass the loop variable to the get variable? I've haven't  found smth on the internet yet...

Thanks if someone knows a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a variable with the desired name:

```
{$user_name='user_'|cat:$foreach_current_user_id}
{if $smarty.get.$user_name == "on"}checked{/if}
```